# Getting Error KeyVaultParameterReferenceAuthorizationFailed, while deploying Logic App using ARM templates(CICD)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

The Key Vault i have created is in another resource group and i am deploying the Logic app to other resource group in which i have referenced the key valut secrets as :

```
>    "azureblob_1_accessKey": {
>       "reference": {
>         "keyVault": {
>           "id": "/subscriptions/5a7084cb-3357-4ee0-b28f-a3230de8b337/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/KeyVault"
>         },
>         "secretName": "AppSettings--StorageAccessValue--DEV"
>       }
>     },
```

I am deploying the logic apps using CICD but in release definition i am getting following error :

> KeyVaultParameterReferenceAuthorizationFailed: The client
>   '648fa2cc-6cd1-49fa-a11a-ad6a276916cc' with object id
>   '648fa2cc-6cd1-49fa-a11a-ad6a276916cc' does not have permission to
>   perform action 'MICROSOFT.KEYVAULT/VAULTS/DEPLOY/ACTION' on the
>   specified KeyVault resource
>   '/subscriptions/5a7084cb-3357-4ee0-b28f-a3230de8b337/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/KeyVault'.
>   Please see https://aka.ms/arm-keyvault for usage details. undefined
>
> **

**How to find resource related to ID given in error?**

**

Comment: I think you need to add this client id `648fa2cc-6cd1-49fa-a11a-ad6a276916cc` in your KeyVault Access policies

Comment: @Jayendran How to add client id ?

Comment: @JoyWang I am deploying using Release Definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error , the user does not have the `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/deploy/action` permission.

If a key vault is referenced in a template deployment, you should note:

**1**.Make sure `enabledForTemplateDeployment` is `true`, you could check it in the portal, refer to the screenshot.

[image]

**2**.Make sure the user deploying the template must have the `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/deploy/action` permission for scope that contains the Key Vault including resource group and Key Vault. The `Owner` and `Contributor` roles both grant this access.

To add permission, you could use [role-based access control (RBAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal) to do it, navigate to the `Access control (IAM)` in the portal -> `Add` , select a role of `Owner` or `Contributor`. Besides, you can also create a role with the minimum permssion, and  assign the user, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter#enable-access-to-the-secret).

For more details, refer to : [Use Azure Key Vault to pass secure parameter value during deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter).